# generate R function to filter data from a new object

Tags: r, function, filter, bioinformatics

I’m trying to develop a new object (for bioinformatics), so I want to extract information from the some elements of the object, and I want to create a function similar to filter of dplyr. The object have a data frame, so I want to filter information from it, but the problem is that some columns of the data.frame are always present, but some of them not, so I want to create a function that extract using the columns that are not always present.

Something like:

```
my_function(object, parametersXYZ){
    data <- object@gene_table
    #generate the filter 
    result <- filter(data, parametersXYZ)
    return(results)
}
```

In this sense, parametersXYZ correspond to the **column**, the **logical operator** (==, !=, %in%) and the **element** to filter, so the function will be use like

```
my_function(myobject, genes == “rtxA”)
```

so the function will filter all the **rtxA** elements in the column **gene**. I was looking for examples but I just didn’t find it, so I tried to check the code of filter on dplyr, but I’m not sure how to implement it !!!

this is an example of the data.frame

```
myobject[["gene_table"]] %>% head()

        cluster         qseqid    bp nseqs     sample gene   VF
1 cluster_00001 IOHEFJOD_02210 15627    20 Sample-001 rtxA rtxA
2 cluster_00001 CJMKIBHP_00364 15621    20 Sample-002 rtxA rtxA
3 cluster_00001 JEJKLKDJ_00421 15621    20 Sample-003 rtxA rtxA
4 cluster_00001 MOOCIOKH_00638 15621    20 Sample-004 rtxA rtxA
5 cluster_00001 HJJCNJPA_01986 15621    20 Sample-005 rtxA rtxA
6 cluster_00001 MDIJOING_00449 15621    20 Sample-006 rtxA rtxA
```

the first 4 columns are always present, but the rest could present different names, or even could have any number of columns, those columns are my problem !!!

Any manual, suggestion or idea
Thanks so much !!!

Comment: Can you show the `dput(head(myobject, 20))`  Wouldn't your function declaration would be `my_function <- function(object, parametersXY) {...}`

Comment: How is it that you are using `[[` extractor on S4 class? I doubt you should use `@` probably you meant to use `$`

Comment: Thanks so much, you are right, I have to use @, Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get evaluated

```
 my_function <- function(object, parametersXYZ){
      filter(object@gene_table, {{parametersXYZ}})
}
```

-testing without using the `object@gene_table`

```
> my_function(iris, Species == "setosa") %>% head
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 1):

In Base R you could do:

```
my_function <- function(object, parametersXYZ){
  par <- substitute(parametersXYZ)
  dat <- object@gene_table
  subset(dat, eval(par, dat))
}
```